# Unique indexes took from other entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have the next classes:

```
public class Y_Equipment
{
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string CategoryDisplayName{get;set;}
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Key]
    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment",2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string CategoryCode{get;set;}
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string EquipmentDisplayName{get;set;}
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment",3, IsUnique = true)]        
    public string EquipmentCode{get;set;}
    public Int32 Timespamp{get;set;}

    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual Y_Unit Unit { get; set; }
}

public class Y_Unit : Item
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Flag { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string UnitSubType { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string UnitSubTypeID { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Item
{
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [Index("IX_EntityCode",1,IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [Key]
    public string Code{get;set;}
}
```

And my problem is the next one:
I want to have 3 item index unique key on Y_Equipments and 1 part of that combination should be the foreign key form Y_Unit[code](the 3le element combination can't repeat).

IE:

- 'Cat1','Equip1','Unit1',
- 'Cat1','Equip1','Unit2'
- 'Cat1','Equip2','Unit2'

but not

- 'Cat1','Equip1','Unit1' again

But instead I get something like

```
 CreateIndex("dbo.Y_Equipment", new[] { "CategoryCode", "EquipmentCode" }, unique: true, name: "IX_Y_Equipment");
 CreateIndex("dbo.Y_Equipment", "Unit_Code");
```

And this is no what I want... Any hint how to update correctly my entity? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can add indexes to navigation properties. Try adding the `UnitID` foreign key to the `Y_Equipment` class and put the attribute on that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
today I stayed and read more about EF and found a way to do this.

My result when I script create the index:

```
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Y_Equipment]    Script Date: 12/5/2014 10:26:10 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Y_Equipment] ON [dbo].[YB_Equipment]
(
    [Unit_Code] ASC,
    [CategoryCode] ASC,
    [EquipmentCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How I did it? I added the Foreign key by myself and mapped it to index and now my class looks like:

```
public class Y_Equipment
{
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string CategoryDisplayName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Key]
    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string EquipmentDisplayName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    public string EquipmentCode { get; set; }
    public Int32 Timespamp { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Y_Equipment", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [ForeignKey("Unit")]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string Unit_Code { get; set; }

    public virtual Y_Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

This is exactly what I wanted. And I want to say thank you to @Colin cause he game me a hint how to do it.